# Arduino Uno: Capturing MIDI from Cubase to turn on RECORDING sign when PLAY, STOP, RECORD is pressed

Tags: arduino, midi

I wanted a lighted RECORDING sign to change colors based on the play state of my recording software.  I wrote the Arduino code below to turn on one of three relays (LED Lights) when I press either STOP, PLAY, or RECORD in the music software Cubase.  When pressed, Cubase transmits these midi strings:

```
Cubase sends "B0 0C 0E   B0 2C 44" when it begins to PLAY
Cubase sends "B0 0C 0E   B0 2C 43" when it begins to STOP
Cubase sends "B0 0C 0E   B0 2C 45" when it begins to RECORD
```

I had code that found the first BYTE, then waited for the second BYTE.  But that was unnecessary.

All I need is, for example, is "B0 2C 44"  (or 176-44-68 decimal) to appear, and I turn on the PLAY (Green) LED.

**It works.**

However, not all the time.  Every fourth or fifth time, it doesn't sense it. I put the hardware I'm using in the notes.

I've done days of research and am aware of others who are experiencing the same issue, but I can't seem to find a solution.  Thanks for any advice you may have.

---

```cpp
/*RECORDING SIGN for Steinberg Cubase Pro 11
Copyright (c) 2021 by Tom Sylvester, Inc. A North Carolina Corp
Feel free to use this code in your own project.  Just credit me.
Monitoring MidiOX, I determined:
Cubase sends "B0 0C 0E   B0 2C 44" when it begins to PLAY
Cubase sends "B0 0C 0E   B0 2C 43" when it begins to STOP
Cubase sends "B0 0C 0E   B0 2C 45" when it begins to RECORD
Cubase sends "B0 0C 0E   B0 2C 42" when it begins to SCRUB FWD
Cubase sends "B0 0C 0E   B0 2C 41" when it begins to SCRUB REW
Cubase sends "B0 0C 0F   B0 2C 43" when LOOP is set to ON
Cubase sends "B0 0C 0F   B0 2C 03" when LOOP is set to OFF
The following code takes these strings and turns the LED Relays On/Off.
    
PARTS:
Arduino Uno R3 Microcontroller ($14)
UBld.it MIDI Breakout Board ($12)
HiLetgo 5V 4 Channel Relay Shield ($8)
5V LED Strip Light ($9)
Striveday 22 AWG 5 conductor wire ($18)
FORE MIDI to USB Interface MIDI Cable Adapter ($20)
Wolfwhoop PW-D Control Buck Converter 6-24V to 5V
1.5A Step-Down Regulator Module Power Inverter Volt Stabilizer ($2)
9V DC Adapter ($9)  
Radio Shack Project Enclosure (5x2x2.5) ($10)
SUBTOTAL: $93
Custom Etched Acrylic Logo (8.5x11x.25) approx $22
TOTAL: $115
*/
    
// VARIABLES
int dataStop = 67;
int dataPlay = 68;
int dataRecord = 69;
int dataFwd = 66;
int dataRev = 65;
int StayOnRecord = 0;
  
// MIDI 
byte status1;
byte data11;
byte data12;
    
// RELAYS
#define relay2Blue 6
#define relay3Green 5
#define relay4Red 4
    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(31250);
  pinMode(relay2Blue, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay3Green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay4Red, OUTPUT); 
  digitalWrite(relay2Blue, HIGH); // TURN ON BLUE RELAY (#2) INITIALLY
}
   
void checkMIDI() {
  do {
    if (Serial.available()) {
      status1 = Serial.read(); // read first byte
      data11 = Serial.read();  // read next byte
      data12 = Serial.read();  // read final byte

      // STOP
      if ((status1 == 176) && (data11 == 44) && (data12 == dataStop)) {
        StayOnRecord = 0;
        digitalWrite(relay2Blue, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(relay3Green, LOW);
        digitalWrite(relay4Red, LOW);
      }
    
      // RECORD
      if ((status1 == 176) && (data11 == 44) && (data12 == dataRecord)) {
        StayOnRecord = 1;
        digitalWrite(relay2Blue, LOW);    
        digitalWrite(relay3Green, LOW);
        digitalWrite(relay4Red, HIGH);
      }
                          
      // PLAY
      if ((status1 == 176) && (data11 == 44) && (data12 == dataPlay)) {
        if (StayOnRecord == 0) { // Cubase sends a PLAY command after RECORD, so this keeps PLAY (GREEN) from lighting up during RECORD (RED)
          digitalWrite(relay2Blue, LOW);    
          digitalWrite(relay3Green, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(relay4Red, LOW);
        }
        StayOnRecord = 0; // ...then RESETs it.
      }
    
      // FAST FORWARD
      if ((status1 == 176) && (data11 == 44) && (data12 == 66)) {
        for (int i=1; i<=6 ; i++) { 
          digitalWrite(relay2Blue, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(relay4Red, LOW); 
          digitalWrite(relay3Green, HIGH); // TURN ON ALL RELAYS
          delay(20);
          digitalWrite(relay2Blue, LOW);
          digitalWrite(relay4Red, LOW); 
          digitalWrite(relay3Green, LOW);  // TURN OFF ALL RELAYS
          delay(20);
        }
        digitalWrite(relay3Green, LOW);
        digitalWrite(relay4Red, LOW);
        digitalWrite(relay2Blue, HIGH);    // TURN ON BLUE RELAY (#2)
        StayOnRecord = 0;
        delay(10);
      }
    
      // FAST REVERSE
      if ((status1 == 176) && (data11 == 44) && (data12 == 65)) {
        for (int i=1; i<=6 ; i++) { 
          digitalWrite(relay2Blue, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(relay4Red, LOW); 
          digitalWrite(relay3Green, HIGH); // TURN ON ALL RELAYS
          delay(20);
          digitalWrite(relay2Blue, LOW);
          digitalWrite(relay4Red, LOW); 
          digitalWrite(relay3Green, LOW);  //TURN OFF ALL RELAYS
          delay(20);
        }
        digitalWrite(relay3Green, LOW);
        digitalWrite(relay4Red, LOW);
        digitalWrite(relay2Blue, HIGH);    //TURN ON BLUE RELAY (#2)
        StayOnRecord = 0;
        delay(10);
      }
    }
  }
  while (Serial.available() > 2); // when at least three bytes available   
}
    
void loop(){
  checkMIDI();
  delay(10);
}
```

Arduino, with Relay Shield:

[image]

Working Recording Sign:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cool project!

Each time through `loop()` you call your `checkMIDI()`, which tests if a character is available, but then tries to read **three** values. Changing the `do while` to a `while (Serial.available() >= 3) { ... }` might fix it, and that might be enough.

One option - use a MIDI library, and let it do the collecting and parsing for you. You would define a callback to get the CC commands, and decide what to do with them. https://github.com/FortySevenEffects/arduino_midi_library

Another option, re-do your scanning to set some flags, and use the `loop()`. Here's a rough skeleton:

```
const byte IDLE = 0, NEEDCC = 1, NEEDNUM = 2;

byte midiscanstate = IDLE;

// this is inside loop()
if serial available
    b = serial read
    switch midiscanstate
    case IDLE
        if b == B0
            midiscanstate = NEEDCC
    case NEEDCC
        if b == 0x2C
            midiscanstate = NEEDNUM
        else
            midiscanstate = IDLE
    case NEEDNUM
        doaction(b)
        midiscanstate = IDLE
    default
        midiscanstate = IDLE
```

Draw out the states and the bytes which change state to make sure I've got it right. I think that will work.  (should probably ignore midi real-time messages if they get in the way).  HTH! Have fun!

Comment: thanks so much.  I'm getting closer.  I used your recommended CallBack and it properly goes to the procedure. But I have no way of seeing the contents of status1, data11, nor data12.  I presume it's expecting hex.  I can have it turn on lights from within the procedure.  But without an IF..THEN or CASE to determine the variables, I'm stuck.  Perhaps you can tell me how to get a SERIAL MONITOR working at other than 9600 so I can see what status1, data11, and data12 are.  I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

@aMike, thanks for your thoughts. Your Callback recommendation is *ALMOST* working.  It's going to the **doCC** callback below (I tested it with **!= 0** and also by simply turning on relays within the procedure).  But in order to do an **IF..THEN** or **CASE**,  I need to know what **status1**, **data11**, and **data12** are coming back as.  Alas, with no Serial Monitor available (<>9600 baud), I'm in a room with the lights out.  It should be sending "**B0 2C 44**" but apparently it's not.  You've been very helpful--ALMOST THERE!

```
#include <MIDI.h>
MIDI_CREATE_DEFAULT_INSTANCE();
void handleControlChange(byte status1, byte data11, byte data12);

// VARIABLES
byte dataStop = 0x43;
byte dataPlay = 0x44;
byte dataRecord = 0x45;
int StayOnRecord = 0;
  
// RELAYS
#define relay2Blue 6
#define relay3Green 5
#define relay4Red 4
    
void doCC(byte status1, byte data11, byte data12)
{
      // STOP
      if ((status1 == 0xB0) && (data11 == 0x2C) && (data12 == 0x43)) {
        StayOnRecord = 0;
        digitalWrite(relay2Blue, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(relay3Green, LOW);
        digitalWrite(relay4Red, LOW);
      }
    
      // RECORD
      if ((status1 == 0xB0) && (data11 == 0x2C) && (data12 == 0x45)) {
        StayOnRecord = 1;
        digitalWrite(relay2Blue, LOW);    
        digitalWrite(relay3Green, LOW);
        digitalWrite(relay4Red, HIGH);
      }
                          
      // PLAY
      if ((status1 == 0xB0) && (data11 == 0x2C) && (data12 == 0x44)) {
        if (StayOnRecord == 0) {                  // Cubase sends a PLAY command after RECORD, so this keeps PLAY (GREEN) from lighting up during RECORD (RED)
          digitalWrite(relay2Blue, LOW);    
          digitalWrite(relay3Green, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(relay4Red, LOW);
        }
        StayOnRecord = 0;                         // ...then RESETs it.
      }
}


void setup() {
  pinMode(relay2Blue, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay3Green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay4Red, OUTPUT); 
  digitalWrite(relay2Blue, HIGH);               // TURN ON the BLUE LED Relay (#2) INITIALLY

    MIDI.begin(MIDI_CHANNEL_OMNI);             // Listen on all channels
//    MIDI.turnThruOff();          
    MIDI.setHandleControlChange(doCC);    
}


void loop()
{
  MIDI.read();
}
```

Comment: We're almost there!  The MIDI library is doing a lot of the processing and decoding for you. Your callback gets the channel number, not the whole status byte.
I might turn around the tests and `return` ASAP; it will simplify your `if` statements:

    `if (chan != 0) return;`
    `if (ccnum != 0x2C) return;`
    `// now switch on the CC value ...`

Very important - your callback should not use `delay` or do anything that takes time. Also, the Uno has only one serial port, used by MIDI, so we can't print to serial monitor.

Comment: Thank you SO much, @aMike !  You were spot on.  I cannot thank you enough!  The code works perfectly now with absolute perfection--no dropouts!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks SO much, @aMike.  Your ideas were SPOT ON.  This code works perfectly, now, with zero drop-outs:

```
#include <MIDI.h>
MIDI_CREATE_DEFAULT_INSTANCE();
void handleControlChange(byte status1, byte data11, byte data12);

// VARIABLES
byte dataStop = 0x43;
byte dataPlay = 0x44;
byte dataRecord = 0x45;
byte dataFFWD = 0x42;
byte dataFREV = 0x41;
int StayOnRecord = 0;
  
// RELAYS
#define relay2Blue 6
#define relay3Green 5
#define relay4Red 4
    
void doCC(byte status1, byte data11, byte data12){
     // get note value
      status1 = MIDI.getChannel();
      data11 = MIDI.getData1();
      data12 = MIDI.getData2();

      // STOP
      if (data12 == dataStop) {
        StayOnRecord = 0;
        digitalWrite(relay2Blue, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(relay3Green, LOW);
        digitalWrite(relay4Red, LOW);
      }
    
      // RECORD
      if (data12 == dataRecord) {
        StayOnRecord = 1;
        digitalWrite(relay2Blue, LOW);    
        digitalWrite(relay3Green, LOW);
        digitalWrite(relay4Red, HIGH);
      }
                          
      // PLAY
      if (data12 == dataPlay) {
        if (StayOnRecord == 0) {                  // Cubase sends a PLAY command after RECORD, so this keeps PLAY (GREEN) from lighting up during RECORD (RED)
          digitalWrite(relay2Blue, LOW);    
          digitalWrite(relay3Green, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(relay4Red, LOW);
        }
        StayOnRecord = 0;                         // ...then RESETs it.
      }

      // Fast FWD
      if (data12 == dataFFWD) {
        StayOnRecord = 0;
        digitalWrite(relay2Blue, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(relay3Green, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(relay4Red, LOW);
      }

      // Fast REV
      if (data12 == dataFREV) {
        StayOnRecord = 0;
        digitalWrite(relay2Blue, LOW);
        digitalWrite(relay3Green, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(relay4Red, HIGH);
      }


}


void setup() {
  pinMode(relay2Blue, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay3Green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay4Red, OUTPUT); 
  digitalWrite(relay2Blue, HIGH);               // TURN ON the BLUE LED Relay (#2) INITIALLY
  MIDI.begin(MIDI_CHANNEL_OMNI);               // Listen on all channels
  MIDI.turnThruOff();          
  MIDI.setHandleControlChange(doCC);    
}


void loop()
{
  MIDI.read();
}
```